# Surviving Re-entry in only a space suit

Tags: internal-consistency, space-travel, atmosphere, survival

**Because who needs a space craft?**

*Picture this:*
While performing a routine spacewalk, outside your small, 1-man space pod, a fault in the propulsion system controls causes the pod to explode, launching you into a *low orbit* of the Earth.
Now with a limited air supply, and only your own space suit & MMU (Manned Manuvering Unit) at your disposal, **you are tasked with re-entering Earth's atmosphere, in a survivable manner**. (Please note, that chance of survival does not need to be 100%).
*The Question:*
Is it scientifically possible to survive re-entry in this manner, and if so how? **If not**, and if it would be possible, if the scenario were to be modified, please describe how it could be modified, in order to make it possible.

**Note:**
Your MMU does *not* need to be of the modern NASA variety. The story is set in the near future, so the design can be slightly more advanced (but still within reason for an MMU).

***Edit:**
Originally, I had planned for the MMU to provide a wireless transceiver (allowing the astronaut to calculate his re-entry angle based on GPS signals?), a set of manuvering thrusters which set his re-entry vector & slow him down to prevent a crash - if possible, and possibly the material needed to construct a rudimentary heat-shield (if such material would feasibly be used in construction of an MMU).*

Comment: Would you be orbiting the Earth six or seven km / second?  If so, no.

Comment: You can be orbiting at any feasible speed. Plus the thrusters on your MMU could be used to alter your speed (to a realistic extent) if necessary.

Comment: They might as well say, "You're gonna die Jeff".

Comment: Check out this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOOSE

Comment: I assumed your MMU to be something like a near-future EVA setup, in which case, absolutely not.  Further to this, I would expect your destroyed space pod would have the only chance of things like a parachute?  I'm not trying to be contrary, because I think it's a good question (+1), it just seems like a dead end to me.  The answers will be good here though.   Maybe define what's included with the MMU that's not included with the 1-Man Space Pod?

Comment: This sounds like a typical Kerbal Space Program Problem... you may grab yourself a copy and try it for yourself; I once landed a Kerbal in a suite from orbit somehow by doing a half-planet-air-break. However, its still pretty far from reality, but a light-weight object may get slow enough before its igniting thanks to friction-heat....

Comment: Unless you have a MOOSE strapped to your EVA suit, you are fried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many problems to overcome:

According to [NASA](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/asteroids/overview/fastfacts.html), most meteors of a radius of `80 feet` burn up in the atmosphere so that they cause little to no damage. So, we need to somehow cool off our poor guy so that he isn't a pile of ashes by the time he hits (or floats, if he was ashes) to the ground. Add a very potent **coolant system** or **heat shield**.

Now that we've solved burning up, we still have to consider landing. Terminal velocity at sea-level for an upright human is about 200 mph. Most meteors burn up around 30 miles, so our friend would have to decelerate in a "mere" 30 miles, either requiring a reverse propulsion system to boost him upward, or a parachute. The former would also require some kind of stabilization system, such as gyroscopes, to avoid flipping over. The problem with a upward thrust is that gravity will push down when you are not at terminal velocity, so you would have to supply a continuous thrust of around `9.9 m/s^2` for about `10` minutes to slow him down to land safely (which is impractical), so you would need a **parachute**. To be safe, we also include a upward-accelerating **jetpack** to ensure a safe *landing*.

---

All in all, your chances for survival are fairly slim, but it could be possible to survive such a fall.

Comment: Thank you for such a practical analysis of the problem (+1).  Out of curiosity, do you think it would be feasible for our astronaut to re-configure his MMU in order to provide the thrust which you mentioned?

Comment: Unlikely if he is floating around in space. Even if he was inside a space station, I doubt he could figure out how to even if it was possible.

Comment: We can dispense with the parachute.  He's got quite a range of places to land and presumably good guidance as to the deorbit burn and where to aim.  His target should be a place that lacks things sticking up and has just received a huge snowfall.  Extremely dangerous but potentially survivable.

Comment: Pretty good summary of the issues, but you missed the first one: getting into re-entry in the first place. Unless the hapless voyager can alter his orbit enough to re-enter, he will just orbit forever. Not every orbit that intersects the upper atmosphere is a re-entry: if you come in too shallow, the atmospheric shock just bounces you back up!

Comment: (And the delta V needed for this manoeuvre is  vastly more than real world EVA kits can provide: for example, the MMU does a maximum of 23.4 m/s. when you need km/s.)

Comment: @Securiger If your "low" orbit dips deep enough into the atmosphere (say, below 90 km or so), you'll reenter after one or two orbits.  Aerobraking is surprisingly effective, and use of remaining MMU propellant can "improve" this significantly (thrusting toward Earth halfway from apogee to perigee will lower perigee by raising apogee -- but the aerobraking will lower apogee for you).

Comment: Meteors are hitting the atmosphere at anywhere from 11 to 72 km/s, with most in the 30-40 km/s range. Since kinetic energy, which is going to effect how "hard" you hit the atmosphere, increases with the square of the speed a typical meteor at, say, 30 km/s will have about 16 times the amount of kinetic energy compared to something of the same mass coming in from Low Earth Orbit.

Answer (score 6):

If this sort of scenario was considered likely, the MMU might incorporate a "ballute".

This is a low mass substitute for a reentry heat shield, and has the added bonus of being an air bag for your final landing. Real life use includes being used to retard bombs (so the bomber can escape the blast) and this has been proposed for real life space missions. The movie 2010 has the Russian spacecraft using a ballet to aerobrake in the orbit of Jupiter, so the technique is versatile.

[image]

[image]

Now this might not be a common thing to add to an MMU, since while lighter than a heat shield, the mass of the fabric and gas bottles to inflate the Ballute will still be considerable, and make manoeuvring in space slow and unwieldy (you will also require far more fuel for your MMU to work). It would be like suggesting you always carry a parachute and a backpack full of survival gear for both desert and arctic conditions, on the off chance you fall out of an airplane or window.

For your scenario, if the construction shack can't send a rescue pod out quickly enough to pick up the unfortunate astronaut, they might be able to launch a "reentry pack" with prepackaged ballute, inflation gear, extra oxygen, survival kit and a powerful solid fuel rocket motor. It intercepts the astronaut, who rapidly straps it on (or the robotic arms on the device grab him and pull him aboard), then it orients itself, the solid fuel motor fires to begin reentry and the ballet inflates. For simplicity, the device might actually be designed to land on water so the ballute becomes an improvised life raft as well (using it as an airy bag on land might bounce you face first into the desert floor....).

Happy landings

Comment: While still not quite as epic a solution as I had originally been hoping for, your solution is both realistic and practical (assuming I can find a way for our unfortunate astronaut to acquire one of these ballute systems). I will certainly consider it if I can't find a way to achieve re-entry using the materials that are already in the astronaut's possession (+1). Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Don't stand too close to windows, though ;-)

Comment: Solid combustibles to inflate the ballute are a lot lower mass than gas bottles.  Not like the sodium azide capsules that (explosively) inflate auto air bags, more like the lithium perchlorate "candles" that have been emergency oxygen generators since the earliest Soviet space stations (ideally producing something that doesn't support combustion, like carbon dioxide and nitrogen).

Comment: The ballute pack might actually be included in the pod (in case something goes wrong) and so the astronaut has to get to the debris and search them to find the pack.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it is possible, it won't happen; since the astronaut was in a space pod, his or her suit probably wasn't designed for re-entry. A space suit strong enough to withstand re-entry would be so bulky and reinforced, it might as well be a small spaceship.

Of course, the odds that this astronaut survived the pod explosion to begin with are, shall we say, astronomical.

Answer (score 2):

See [MOOSE project of General Electric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOOSE) designed in the early 1960s - only 90 kg. I bet that with modern materials we could make it even lighter.

[image]

The key to make re-entry easier is to increase surface to mass ratio. If you have good ratio then even [paper plane made from silicone treated paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_planes_launched_from_space) would survive.

Answer (score 0):

The real concern with this situation isn't related to falling to Earth (gravitational potential energy), but to the problem of kinetic energy.

Anything in low-Earth orbit travels at a high speed:

> The mean orbital velocity needed to maintain a stable low Earth orbit is about 7.8 km/s (28,000 km/h; 17,000 mph)
> — [Low Earth orbit - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit)

Using round numbers, an astronaut and environmental equipment might weigh 100kg.
100kg, traveling at high speed has a lot of energy:

```
E = mv²

m = 100 kg
v = 7.8 km/s

E = 100 kg × (7.8 km/s)²
  = 100 × 60 km² / s²
  = 6 000 000 000 m²s⁻²
  = 6 GJ
```

So, before you can even think about what happens when falling down, you have to do something with all that kinetic energy *before* you are even *able* to fall down.

According to [Kyle's Converter](http://www.kylesconverter.com/energy,-work,-and-heat/gigajoules-to-tons-of-tnt), 6 gigajoules is as much energy as in 1.4 tons of TNT.

1.4 tons of TNT produces a serious amount of heat, and you will be at the center of that process.

Forget about re-entry.
Imagine you're on solid ground here on Earth, sitting on 1.4 tons of TNT.
What are your chances of surviving when that energy is released, even if its release were slowed down enough to not be an explosion?

To say you would be toast would be an incredible understatement.

Answer (score -1):

Let's see what happens:

First, you have to enter on a very narrow angle.  Too deep, you black out, tumble and die.  Too shallow, you bounce and you probably run out of life support before you come back down.  That's an accuracy you're not going to accomplish by eyeball.

Second, as you enter you need to maintain just the right shape to cause the shockwave to flow around you rather than touch your suit anywhere.  You lose orientation, the plasma gets to your suit and you burn.

Third, even if the plasma doesn't touch you it's very, very hot.  Most of that energy becomes hot air behind you but you're going to pick up some of it.  You're going to need unobtainium insulation on your suit if you want something thin enough that you can actually move about in your suit.  Oh, but if your suit is that well insulated how did you keep from cooking yourself while you were in space??

Fourth, the deorbit maneuver requires actual rockets, something that is unlikely to be on a suit for safety reasons.  Cold gas thrusters aren't good enough.

There's only one way to survive the trip:  Change your species to Kerbal. :)  (And even then you need to burn the 600 m/s in your jetpack to shed some of the 2,300 m/s orbital velocity you have.)

Answer (score -3):

Given you had enough supplies, you could force an intercept to a space station. If you had 60 m/s, and some solar panels to power life support, you might not be screwed. But the force in reentry would almost surely kill you. Even taking the heatshield from your pod, pushing it to a deorbit trajectory, and duct-taping yourself to it after covering the heatsheild with the pods cover to ensure wake stability is better.

Comment: According to the question, this scenario occurs because the worker has become separated from the (exploded) pod, which likely didn't have a heat shield anyway (not designed to reenter or aerobrake).

Comment: Unless your pod was in an orbit that planned to take it to that space station, there is almost certainly not going to be a space station in LEO that you can reach with a survivable relative velocity if you only have 60 m/s of delta-V in the tank.

Comment: aerobraking my fellows, what if it is a comsat mission in a 300 km orbit, aerobraking can get you there. They can detach a soyuz to help you.