# I am entering Venus atmosphere in only a space suit. Can I survive?

Tags: space, planets, emergency

DISCLAIMER: No, this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34036/surviving-re-entry-in-only-a-space-suit). We are talking about reentering Venus' atmosphere as opposed to Earth, and the suit parameters are rather different to a current suit.

Background:

A terrorist has detonated a bomb on the main character's ship, in low equatorial orbit ~200 km above Venus. They are on a hull inspection EVA at the time, and to escape the blast hide behind one of the many auxiliary craft on the ship, a biological sample pod designed to evaluate habitability of Venus' atmosphere. Unfortunately, the explosion triggers the automatic debris avoidance program and activates the pod's engine in such a way that the character and biopod are now on an atmospheric entry trajectory.

The suit is made with carbon nanotube fabric in most places, except where impossible. There, they use standard MMU-like materials. The suit has a delta-v comparable to [SAFER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Aid_For_EVA_Rescue), an oxygen reserve of 8 hours and a parachute to be used in emergency deorbit situations. Mass is 70 kilograms.

The biopod is not designed to survive surface conditions on Venus, its purpose being to float in the atmosphere at an altitude of 30-50 km to test survivability of microorganisms in this environment.

Can they survive this situation(i.e land on Venus or return to ship successfully, with survivability for the nominal EVA duration)? If not, what is needed to allow it?

I appreciate your feedback. Thank you!

Comment: Is this auxiliary craft capable of landing?

Comment: @Alexander No, it is designed to float in the atmosphere at an altitude of ~30-50km.

Comment: Aha, so it's never has to be exposed to the pressure and temperature at the surface level. I think you should mention that in the question.

Comment: Ok, this is not exactly what I had in mind. Does the pod (or the suit, by any chance) has any landing (or upper atmosphere gliding) capabilities (engines, parachutes etc.)? Without those, it will be certainly doomed.

Comment: @Alexander The pod has propulsion systems that are designed to keep it stable and relaunch from Venus atmosphere, but no landing gear or parachutes. The suit has a parachute in case of emergency.

Comment: So the answer depends on whether the pod can stay in the upper atmosphere or the parachute is adequate for landing from high altitude. Only in that case the question of atmospheric composition becomes relevant. Also (just thinking), if designers had provided the suit with such adequate parachute, they must have made the suit suitable for the surface conditions, at least for a short time.

Comment: @Alexander The designers anticipated Earth reentry, not Venus entry. Would the suit even initially survive entry heat and plasma?

Comment: If the pod is gliding at 30-50 km, it is already at suborbital speed, so "heat and plasma" are much less of a concern. If the pod has failed to slow down before descending to that altitude or below, then it's game over for the pod and its passengers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111460/discussion-between-lelu-and-alexander).

Comment: While Willk's answer is sensible it is generally considered best to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer. This also improves the probability of having more answers to your question.

Comment: Consider the end of Dr Stangelove at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJ4ffTLdSZU

Design your suit with the necessary capabilities and only bad luck should make it fail…

Answer (score 19):

No, you would burn up in the atmosphere of Venus. The Safer unit can supply an orbital delta V of perhaps 3 m/s, whilst orbital speed around Venus will be very roughly 8000 m/s so it won't make any difference. The parachute would not work at orbital speeds, it would be shredded and burnt. Even with sufficient braking the atmosphere is so dense and hot that you would die long before reaching the ground.

Further to editing of the original question:
Plan B suggestion - use a heat shield to shed most of the orbital speed then jettison it and use a ballute inflated with oxygen/nitrogen to slow further still. Very tricky but if you do it right and use a few atm pressure to inflate the ballute you could end up floating in the atmosphere of Venus high up where the temperature is around 20 degrees C. Then climb into the ballute and await rescue. Not good but much better than trying to land.

Comment: Also it rains sulfuric acid.

Comment: OK, so what equipment would be needed to survive re entry? I am aware of a hypersonic decelerator or ballute of some kind having been tested, could this be used?

Comment: You will need a very strong protective capsule capable of withstanding a pressure of 93 atmospheres. This is the pressure at around a kilometre down in Earth’s oceans. It must also resist a temperature of 465 degrees C whilst keeping the contents at less than 30-40 degrees C, so will need some very fancy cooling arrangements. Some form of ballute might be used but a heat shield would also be needed ( especially in very of the surface temperature).

Comment: Plan B suggestion - use a heat shield to shed most of the orbital speed then jetison it and use a  ballute inflated with oxygen/nitrogen to slow further still. Very tricky but if you do it right and use around 1 atm pressure to inflate the ballute you could end up floating in the atmosphere of Venus high up where the temperature is around 20 degrees C. Then climb into the ballute and await rescue. Not good but much better than trying to land.

Comment: [Venice is a terrible place.](https://what-if.xkcd.com/30/).

Comment: You can greatly reduce requrements to your suit if you land on [Maxwell Montes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_Montes). It has half the pressure and is a hundred C cooler. It is also easer to launch to orbit from there. It can even host a research base of some sort

Comment: 45 atm and 380 degrees C is a good improvement, but still not really practical. That pressure is equivalent pressure to 500m below sea level and at 380 degrees C it will cook you as you will find it very difficult to keep cool without a heat sink. No doubt the best place for  base, but not a space suit or even a pod.

Comment: @Greg Burghardt - Venice?

Comment: @Slarty, with enough isolation it doesn't matter much is it vacuum around or a frypen. All you have to cool is human body heat production. And modern space suites can do it for hours (by water evoporation). And yes, I agree, Venice is a terrible place - all that smell around!

Comment: Modern space suits are designed to operate in a vacuum not at 45 or 90 bar.

Comment: @Slarty: (sigh) serves me right for commenting on something right before going to bed. Meant Venus. :-P

Answer (score 15):

**Get in the biopod**

The biopod is activated and it is going thru its programmed routine.  The biopod does not land on the surface.  The biopod does not burn up in the atmosphere.  It descends from orbit to float at described height, gathers samples and then returns.

Your character might burn up on the outside of the biopod as it sheds velocity and descends to its sample gathering height.  If he can get in there he will be protected.  It is biopod as escape pod.

Comment: This sure will go down as "that time we found life on Venus" incident in space exploration.

Comment: "[the biopod']s purpose being to float in the atmosphere at an altitude of 30-50 km" it's unclear to me whether OP means that the biopod has a means of simply stopping at that altitude to avoid damage, or if that's just what it's designed to withstand and will simply precipitate to the surface of the planet uncontrollably if there isn't an external force keeping it at the right altitude

Comment: Nevermind, it was addressed in the comments. Your answer is definitely solid

Comment: However the buoyancy of the Biopod will be reduced by the extraweight of the body... Both will end up a little lower in Orbit then planed...

Comment: @T-Me - I bet the biopod has ballast on board.  Like a balloon or ship that has a desired buoyancy it can jettison the ballast as it takes on samples.  That would be good for the fiction - manually clearing out the ballast to make room.